# The difference between common object initialization and initialization in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct student{

   char *name;
   int age;
   int num; 
}; 
int main(){
   student temp;
   cin>>temp;
   cout<<temp.name<<endl;
   student students[2];
   cin>>students[0];
   cout<<students[0].name<<endl;
}

istream& operator >>(istream &in,student& item){
    in>>item.name>>item.age>>item.num;
    return in;
};
```

When I input the information of temp ,the code works well and then output the temp's name.But after I input the information of student[0] and press "Enter" button ,the code fails. I don't know why. Are there some differences between common object initialization and initialization in arrays?

Comment: `item.name` is an invalid pointer.

Comment: Change `char *name` to `std::string name` and all will be well.

Comment: @AlanStokes I know that string is a better choice, but I just want to know why char* is wrong.

Comment: @Kerrek Can you tell me why item.name is an invaild pointer when item is in an array?

Comment: You haven't initialised the pointer to point to anything. In both cases - array and not array - you have undefined behaviour; your first attempt just happens to not fail in an obvious way.

Comment: @Smile: No - *you* tell me why you think you have a *valid* pointer! The onus of producing a valid pointer is on *you* :-)